# Deleting Internet Explorer cache programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, browser-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear temporary internet files via “C#”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256804/clear-temporary-internet-files-via-c)
>   [How to clear browser cache programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306839/how-to-clear-browser-cache-programmatically)

I am trying to delete a file from `Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache` by iterating all directories of this folders and deleting all files in these directories. The problem is that it doesn't delete **.tmp** and **index.dat** files as they are locked by Windows itself.

My question is that: Is there any work around for deleting **.dat** and **.tmp** files **OR** Can I read Index.dat file and delete the entry of specific file which I want to delete from IE Cache?

**Note:** I want to this from C# desktop application not through ASP.NET

Comment: Checkout the following solution: [Clear IE Cache - C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1574.htm)

Comment: I have tried the above posted solution before posting my question but on DeleteUrlCacheEntry() mathod it gives error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." I have tried to google it but havent found concrete solution.